# Excel Macro Timestamp

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I am still having problems with the following code and not sure where to start fixing it.  When a user tries to close, I would like it to save a copy with a timestamp in the current directory where it launched from.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim sFileName As String
Dim sDateTime As String
Dim txtFileName As String

'0. Set new filename with timestamp.
With ThisWorkbook
    sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
    sFileName = "2018 Testy" & sDateTime

'1. Check of Save As was used.
If SaveAsUI = True Then
    Cancel = True

    '2. Call up your own dialog box.  Cancel out if user Cancels in the dialog box.
    txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(sFileName, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")
    If txtFileName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Action Cancelled", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '3. Save the file.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your error/problem?  When do you use `sFileName`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav he does use it at `.GetSaveAsFilename(sFileName` but that still leaves the question "*What is your issue with that code*"?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  yes, sorry missed that. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sDateTime As String

    sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
    sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2018 Testy" & sDateTime

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```